# Sampling distribution of modified multinomial MLE

Tags: maximum-likelihood, multinomial-distribution

I have $n$ observations of a categorical random variable with the following distribution:
$$\text{Categorical}(A\cdot p)$$
Where $A$ is a known $m \times s$ matrix and $p\in\mathbb{R}^s$ ($p_i\geq 0$, $\sum_i p_i=1$) is the parameter I want to estimate. I am currently estimating $p$ by numerically finding the maximum likelihood estimate $\hat p$.

How could I calculate confidence intervals for $\hat p$?

I thought of using the asymptotic efficiency of the MLE, but the Fisher information matrix of $\hat p$ is singular. Also, many components of $\hat p$ turn out to be zero, and I am not sure if I can apply that asymptotic result on the boundaries of the parameter space.

I also thought of bootstrapping, but I think $n$ is not big enough. I feel like I could use some simulation, but I am not sure about how.

Comment: Did you try profile likelihood? (Or Bayes?)

Comment: I am currently using Bayes for this. with a Dirichlet prior (I am trying uniform priors and also more sparse Dirichlet priors). I am not familiar with profile likelihood methods, I will look it up! (also, thanks for paying attention to such an old question!)